# Console speed: PyCharm vs Spyder

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

I have installed both PyCharm and Spyder (from Anaconda2).

However, when I run the exact same code (printing a very large array) from the python console, the console opened from Spyder printed out the array in less than five seconds, whereas the console opened from PyCharm took one minute to process and then printed the array.

I am wondering what is the reason for the difference in "processing time"? I like the auto-complete feature of PyCharm, but from my experience, it is slower than Spyder. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To avoid this problem in Spyder we only allow 500 lines to be shown in the console at a time (*Note*: This limit is configurable by the user)

So I'd say Pycharm's console doesn't have this functionality (although I can't tell that for sure).

Comment: just FYI, see the [intellij discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206900105-Run-configuration-console-size-limit-) where it is described how to properly configure it. For my own purposes, I'm not yet sure how to get the nice integrated plots I see in spyder for data science, so I'm currently sticking with spyder :)

Answer (score -1):

Spyder has an integrated Jupyter Notebook and can show plots inline - comes with autocompletion that is  just as good (if not much better) than PyCharm's terminal...

It comes with a live debugger that's **much** easier on the eye (side-by-side) and can execute code **real damn** fast!!!

Spyder gives you the option to autocomplete words in the console itself - Pycharm just uses the system command prompt/Terminal.